# C# is it bad practice to call an abstract method within the class that declares it?

Tags: c#, events, inheritance, abstract

I have an update method, and I need to check up on whenever an animation is done and what animation that just finished.

The Code in my Abstract class looks like this:

```
    //Checks if we need to restart the animation
    if (currentIndex > sRectangles.Length-1)
    {
        AnimationDone(aniName);
        timeElapsed = 0;
        currentIndex = 0;
    }
```

AnimationDone() is an abstract method, that looks like this:

```
 public abstract void AnimationDone(string name);
```

The code in the class that inherits from the abstract class, and implements the abstract method looks like this:

```
public override void AnimationDone(string name)
{
    if (name.Contains("Attack"))
    {
        Attacking = false;
    }
}
```

So whenever an animation finishes my AnimationDone is called. This works exactly as I want it, but I was wondering if this is bad practice. 'And if it's more correct to create an event that gets triggered every time an animation ends. And then create a new method in my Child class that listens to this event.

Comment: Certainly not, why would it

Comment: No, it's common practice and actually quite useful.

Comment: I think it's the right thing and abstract was developed for a such things.

Comment: That's actually the point of abstract members - so that you can call them from the class that declares them.

Comment: It doesn't really matter, but you might want to change the method name to `OnAnimationDone`, just for clarity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you've done is actually called the [Template Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/template-method-pattern.html), and is a well known software design pattern. So I wouldn't worry about it!